# Difference between Directory's mkdir and new methods

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between the following Ruby methods?

```
Dir.new(string) and Dir.mkdir(string)
```

I can not tell which one to use in which case and what exactly its used for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html

`Dir.new(s)` "returns a new directory object for the named directory". That is, it is used to **open** a directory; if the directory of path `s` does not exist, an exception is thrown.

- With no block, `Dir.open(s)` is a synonym for `Dir.new(s)`. If a block is present, e.g. as in `Dir.open(s) { |d| ... }`, it is passed the directory object `d` as a parameter. The directory is closed at the end of the block, and `Dir.open` returns the value of the block

`Dir.mkdir(s)` **creates** a directory at the path `s` and returns `0` in case of success.